# Salesforce-lightning-cli lint & ES6 const reserved word

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, es6

I am currently writing lightning components and to do so I use Ecmascript2015 standard (Object.assign, const, let, ...).

**Everything works perfectly** but the `https://www.npmjs.com/package/salesforce-lightning-cli` is used to lint my code with the built-in rules and it gives errors when using `const` or `let`.

Will ES6 be fully supported in the future ? So I can leave those eslint issues unresolved.
Or is it better to stay with es5 block-scope ?

Comment: ES5 with use strict would be what's wise to use for now.

Answer (score 4):

It's safe to use ES6 constructs as long as you do not require Lightning to do any transpilation for you to support non ES6 compliant browsers